# Axios no me devuelve un array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Estoy realizando un get a un Json server

**adjunto servidor json**

*http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista*

EL problema esta cuando quiero asignarle esa lista de objetos a otro componente mediante props

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CardsGrid from "../Pages/CardsGrid"

class Axios_cards extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {
            courses : []
        }      
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista')
        .then(response => this.setState({
                courses: response.data
            }))
    }
    render() {
        const {courses} = this.state
        return <CardsGrid courses={courses}/
    }
}

export default Axios_cards;
```

Exactamento lo asigno aqui

```
render() {
        const {courses} = this.state
        return <CardsGrid courses={courses}/>
    }
```

El componente que recibe la lista de objetos como props no recibe el array, ya que hice una validación para verificarlo

**Adjunto el componente al que asigno el array a través de props *

```
const CardsGrid = ({courses}) => (
    <div className="ed-grid m-grid-3">
            {
                Array.isArray(courses) ?
            courses.map( e => 
                <Cards 
                id={e.id} 
                title={e.title} 
                description={e.description}
                image={e.image}
                price={e.price}
                key={e.id}  
                />) : null
            }
        </div>
)
```

Al aplicar console.log(courses) , me sale "undefined", por lo que el array que pido con axios.get no se aplico como propiedad
Estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta javascript y reactjs por lo cual, el error pueda que sea muy obvio o algo muy pequeño :(

Comment: Hola @Jee4nc por lo que veo en el fetch de arriba no estas retornando la promesa de buena forma. then(resp=>resp. json()) para primero recibir el json, luego podrías volver a llamar al método then abajo: then(data=>{this.setState({courses: data})})

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando la funcion [componentdidmount](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

y le agregas un async para que el renderizado espere a que termine tu peticion ajax

```
componentDidMount = async() => {
    let items = await axios.get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista');
    this.setState({
      items: items.data
    });
  }
```

Si con eso persiste el problema y te da algun tipo de error, en lugar de utilizar una funcion para el componente puedes utilizar una clase,

```
import React from 'react';

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('this.props.courses: ', this.props.courses);

    if(!this.props.courses || !this.props.courses.length) return '';

    return <div>
        ... tu contenido
    </div>
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Los llamados a **endpoints** tienen demoras en las cuales intervienen varios factores como por ejemplo, **velocidad de internet** y **velocidad de procesamiento** que debe realizar el servidor que se encarga de retornar la información solicitada.

En tu caso tienes varias formas de solucionar este problema de datos **undefined**

1 - El uso de **defaultProps**

Puedes definir los valores por defecto de tus props al asignar la propiedad especial **defaultProps** de esta forma no tienes que validar que las propiedades sean **undefined**.

```
const CardsGrid = ({ courses }) => (
  <div className="ed-grid m-grid-3">
    {courses.map(e => (
      <Cards
        id={e.id}
        title={e.title}
        description={e.description}
        image={e.image}
        price={e.price}
        key={e.id}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);

CardsGrid.defaultProps = {
  courses: [],
};

export default CardsGrid;
```

2 - Mostrar un **loading** cuando se están solicitando los datos.

```
class Axios_cards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      courses: [],
      isFetching: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista')
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          courses: response.data,
          isFetching: false,
        }),
      )
      .catch(() =>
        this.setState({
          isFetching: false,
        }),
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { courses, isFetching } = this.state;
    return isFetching ? 'Loading...' : <CardsGrid courses={courses} />;
  }
}

export default Axios_cards;
```